# Create Logfile for all fired commands on server

Tags: linux, redhat, log-files, command

I want to maintain logfile for all fired command on server. We have more than 3 admins and I want to monitor all commands which are fired by these. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: 
`vi /etc/bashrc` and append the following line at the end:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

Step 2:

Set the syslogger to trap local6 to a log file by adding this line in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

```
local6.*                /var/log/cmdlog.log
```

The history of all the users will be in one log.

Comment: done but no log found in cmdlog.log

Comment: did you restart rsyslog service?

Comment: yes restarted rsyslog

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that you need to logout and login for it to work if you haven't done that. Can you see the file cmdlog.log on /var/log folder?

Comment: not created yet ...

Comment: can you post /etc/bashrc and /etc/rsyslog.conf

Comment: tailf /var/log/cmdlog.log  [130] --- Please tell me one more thing what is 130 here ?

Comment: Those are return (exit) codes. Check out:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html